# How to adjust the status bar of my slider in my menu?

Tags: view, slider, status

I have a big problem with my slider cause the status bar

Here is the result

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/859893Capturedcran20131006122142.png

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 apparently supports the Status Bar being hidden for some views but not others. To hide it for all views, do the following:

1) Make sure Hide during application launch is still checked, to support previous OS versions. 2) In your Info.plist file, add View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to NO.
3) You may need to "Clean" before building, (I did), but then your app should work as before: no status bar hanging over your views!

read this tutorial
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/